# Problem using grep inside a bash script that run remote on a server

Tags: bash, shell, grep, remote-server

I m using a script that run remote on server via ssh. 
Inside the script I'm using this line from below:

```
ls | grep -oP "\d{4} -\d{2}-\d{2}"
```

On my local machine that run Ubuntu the script work fine.
But when I try to run it remote I got this

```
grep: invalid option -- 'P'
BusyBox v1.24.1 multi-call binary.
Usage: grep [-HhnlLoqvsriwFE] [-m N] [-A/B/C N] PATTERN/-e PATTERN/...-f file [FILE]...
```

The first thing I thought was an alias problem, i tryed

```
type grep
```

Output is: `grep is /bin/grep`   I think this is ok.

What worries me is BusyBox (I do not know what it is) but i think this can be the problem ?

Comment: "The utilities in BusyBox generally have fewer options than their full-featured GNU cousins" - https://busybox.net/about.html

Comment: Thanks for the documentation, it is very useful wow I did not think it exists !! thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `[0-9]` / `[[:digit:]]` instead of `\d` with POSIX BRE (no option) or ERE  (`-E` option):

```
grep -o "[0-9]\{4\} -[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}"
grep -oE "[0-9]{4} -[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}"
```

Note that in the first command you need to escape the braces since unescaped `{` and `}` match literal brace symbols in a POSIX BRE regex. When escaped, they mean *range* (*interval*, *limiting*) quantifiers. And in the second command, POSIX ERE is enabled with `-E`, and the behavior is reverse: when the braces are escaped they are literal chars, else they are quantifiers.

Comment: I would like to thank you for your prompt response and this solve my problem thank you very much !! :)

Have a good day !